# How do I parse values to text boxes from a row of selected cell in a datagridview in a windows forms app?

Tags: c#, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I would like to know how to select a category value from a combo box and the data according to the selection parses to a data grid view from a sql database, after that I want to click on a cell and the data on that cell row must parse to text boxes in the form and I need to make changes to the record and update the record or delete it from the database. I've tried the following code but I keep getting errors.

```
private void dataGridView_StaffDetails_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    string staffType = comboBox_Type.SelectedItem.ToString();
    if (comboBox_Type.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        comboBox_Type.SelectedItem.ToString();

    }
    else
    {
        Btn_Search.Enabled = false;
    }

    //---SQL Command to Select Data
    try
    {
        //---Open Connection
        connection.Open();

        //---SQL Command to Select Data
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from StaffDetails where Staff_Type = '"      + staffType + "' ", connection);

        //---Execute SQL Command
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            //---Read Data and assign to text boxes, radio buttons and combo box
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Txt_FirstName.Text = reader["Customer_FirstName"].ToString();
                Txt_LastName.Text = reader["Customer_LastName"].ToString();
                Txt_Username.Text = reader["Username"].ToString();
                Txt_Password.Text = reader["Password"].ToString();
                Txt_SalaryPerMonth.Text = reader["Salary_Per_Month"].ToString();
                
                string StaffType = reader["Staff_Type"].ToString();
                comboBox_Type.SelectedItem = staffType;

                Btn_Update.Enabled = true;
                Btn_Delete.Enabled = true;

            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry! No record was found ");
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex);
        connection.Close();
    }


}
```

Comment: You should do some reading on data binding in WinForms. Query the database and populate a `DataTable`, bind that to a `BindingSource` and bind that to both the grid and the `TextBoxes`. That's it. When you select a row in the grid, it will be automaticall;y displayed in the `TextBoxes`. Any changes you make in those `TextBoxes` will be reflected in the grid. You can then save changes from the `DataTable` back to the database.

Comment: Yes, I wonder why so many people still laboriously load data into TextBoxes and DataGrids manually and read it out again, and convert the strings back, when it's much easier with data binding. Even better than a DataTable would be to load the data into a class using Dapper, for example.